# Converting application to work without installation of mysql connector on client

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I am creating an attendance application in visual studio 2010 with c# and connecting to a mysql(wamp) database using mysql connector (mysql-connector-net-6.1.6) by adding as a reference. It is working fine without installation of client.

I am not creating a trigger to insert the attendance data in mysql database. my project is combined with a php website and the php web site's data saved in the mysql database. This attendance application is downloaded and opened after the clicking on a link on the website. When uploaded to the server, not all clients installed the connector application. How can I run this application without requiring client installation?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you deploy `MySql.Data.dll` with your application.

If this dll sits next to your executable file, clients won't need to install the `MySql-Connector` package.